# Marking the intersecting area between two circles in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to mark the overlapping area between two circles (like in a Venn Diagram). I figured the way to do this is by drawing two arcs using the two intersecting points and than fill the path using `fill()`.
I know the coordinates of the intersection points, but how do I use that as an input for the `arc()` function?

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(circle1.x,circle1.y,circle1.r, ? , ? ,true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can draw the intersection of 2 shapes using canvas’s globalCompositeOperation**

[image]

The globalCompositeOperation allows you to control which parts of old and new drawings are shown on the canvas.

You can see examples of each compositing mode here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/

We use 2 of these compositing modes to highlight the intersection of your 2 circles:

**source-atop**

Given that the left circle is already draw, source-atop will draw **only the intersecting part** of the right circle.

```
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";
    ctx.arc(circle2.x,circle2.y,circle2.r, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
```

**destination-over**

Given that the left circle is already draw, destination-over will draw the right circle **under the existing** left circle.

```
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
    ctx.arc(circle2.x,circle2.y,circle2.r, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
```

It’s a lot to take in, so you might comment out all the drawing code and then uncomment it one-opration-at-a-time to see what effect each operation has.

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/JGSJ5/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.lineWidth=3;

    var circle1={x:100,y:100,r:50};
    var circle2={x:140,y:100,r:50};


    // draw circle1
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle1.x,circle1.y,circle1.r, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

    // composite mode "source-atop" to draw the intersection
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle="orange";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";
    ctx.arc(circle2.x,circle2.y,circle2.r, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();

    // destination-over to draw fill for circle2 again
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
    ctx.arc(circle2.x,circle2.y,circle2.r, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();

    // back to normal composite mode (newest drawings on top)
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";

    // draw the stroke for circle1 again
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle1.x,circle1.y,circle1.r, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();

    // draw the stroke for circle2 again
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle2.x,circle2.y,circle2.r, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!