# Filling the intersection of two circles with solid colour

Tags: flash, haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I'm trying to make a simple lighting engine that allows me to mix colours in Haxe - I tagged flash because the API is almost identical.
I'm currently rendering coloured circles into a BitmapData and then rendering that over the top of my game, but I'm having a lot of difficulty rendering the intersections between circles.

[image: This is the effect I'm looking for.]

I wondered if there was a way to draw a shape consisting of the intersection of two other shapes (it probably doesn't need to be built into flash, since they're circles so the maths is relatively simple I imagine).
This would make it relatively simple to render two circles, but as soon as I added a third colour it would become really complicated... I could just never use more than two colours in the worst case scenario!

Finally, would it be possible to use some kind of shader to implement this effect? For example, every time I draw a pixel, look at the existing colour and look up the combination of the two (e.g. red+yellow = orange). I know very little about shaders in flash - though I'm using Haxe so it may even be different again!

I don't think it's possible to achieve this effect cleanly with blend modes - horribly bright colours like magenta and cyan get produced pretty quickly from my experiments. I investigated L*a*b* colour space briefly, but it seemed like it would be very complex (and slow) to implement.

Once I've got this effect working, I intend to check pixel positions in the world with the colour map and apply various effects based on the result.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Javascript seems to have this feature built-in: [Marking the intersecting area between two circles in Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045224/marking-the-intersecting-area-between-two-circles-in-canvas)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need/want some pretty complex optimizations, then you could do it the same way it works in js/canvas by using [BitmapData.draw](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw) method with [BlendMode](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/BlendMode.html).

This method can be supplied with [BitmapData](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/BitmapData.html) or [DisplayObject](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) to draw at your target [BitmapData](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/BitmapData.html). So, your options will be to either render your circles to temporary bitmaps and then draw it on resulting [BitmapData](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/BitmapData.html) with `blendMode`(composition) you want, or create vector graphics(programmatically, with [Sprite](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/Sprite.html) and [Graphics](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/Graphics.html)) for your circles and then render it to target [BitmapData](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/BitmapData.html) in the same way(which would be faster I suppose, however less flexible).

Also, one could compose whole circle scene in vector graphics the same was, instead of circle by circle, however I can't recall right now what composition options are available when you programmatically build [Graphics](http://api.haxe.org/flash/display/Graphics.html), but I guess it's worth to look into that way too.