# How to show only the intersecting part of a drawn shape (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, drawing, shapes

I'm try to show the entirety of the green circle, and only the intersecting point of the pink circle.

[context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9hOe.png)

Anyone have any idea if this is possible in Javascript?

```html
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500,500);

}

function draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill(3, 252, 102);
  ellipse(100, 100, 100, 100);

  fill(255, 46, 206, 100);
  ellipse(130,130, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marking the intersecting area between two circles in Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045224/marking-the-intersecting-area-between-two-circles-in-canvas)

Comment: @Max it's unclear if you want to display the intersecting section of the pink circle as the same pink (as in a masked version of the pink circle) or you want to blend colours (as the transparency fill hints). Eitherway, you can look at [`blendMode()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/blendMode) and [`mask()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/mask) (bare in mind, you can use [`PGraphics`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics) to easily draw ellipses, but still apply a mask as you would to any other image).